# Implement QUEUE using PHP

Tags: php, task-queue

I am implementing Bulk SMS in my application with the help of HTTP API's. Since HTTP urls have limit in number of characters to be sent at a time, i cannot request API along with all the numbers at once. So following is the logic i am using

## Input

Number of Phone Number : 10000 
Number of Phone Numbers per Single HTTP API request : 100

## Requirement

A Queue to send 100 request and process 100 response. I am expecting something like "Tornado Queues" (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html)

Comment: Do you have an actual question, a specific issue? Seems like you've got an idea already; and without any code and you showing your work and research, we can't really help you much. This isn't a "give me code" platform, nor a place to dump a to-do list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  Build your own queue using PHP but it will need some sort of DB backing like MySQL or Redis.  I like Redis a lot because it is fast and doesn't cause additional load on my main DB.  [This is a good implementation of a queue using PHP](https://github.com/urbanindo/yii2-queue).  You will need the `pcntl` extension installed if you are going to directly use this example.

Otherwise you can use a 3rd party service that manages the queue and that you communicate with via webhooks.

[This is a good resource](http://queues.io/) for queue options in general and should extend your general knowledge.

Of the top of my head [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/), [RabitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and [IronMQ](https://www.iron.io/platform/ironmq/) are popular solutions.

Comment: I used this (http://programeveryday.com/post/message-queues-php-and-resque/) link to set up the queue. Your answer was very helpful to go through different queues. Thanks for your help.